# The sum of unit vectors from a point in a polyhedron to its $n$ vertices has magnitude $< n-2$

Tags: geometry

> There is a polyhedron with $n$ vertices and a point $O$ inside it. Let
> $e_i$ be a unit vector directed from the point $O$ to the $i$-th
> vertex of the polyhedron. Prove that $$ |e_1+\ldots+e_n|<n-2. $$

This is an exercise from a book in Russian
[How to solve non-standard problems](https://old.mccme.ru/free-books/olymp/KanKov.pdf) (page 11).
Also, I have encountered this problem on several forums, but nowhere have I seen a solution to this problem.

It seems to me that a similar but somewhat simpler problem for the plane can be formulated as follows:

> Let us give an $n$-gon and the point $O$ inside of it. Let $e_i$ be a
> unit vector directed from $O$ to the $i$-th vertex of the $n$-gon.
> Prove that  $$ |e_1+\ldots+e_n|<n-2. $$

My hope was that these problems could be solved with the help of the statements
from the ["About four points lying on a sphere"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4835035) post.

In the plane, for example, the reasoning could be as follows.
Let $e_i=\vec{OA_i}$, $i=1,\ldots,n$.
There are three points $A,B,C\in\{A_1,\ldots,A_n\}$ such that $O$ lies inside triangle $\triangle ABC$.
We can assume without loss of generality that $A=A_1$, $B=B_1$, $C=C_1$.
Then we get
$$
|e_1+\ldots+e_n|\leq|e_1+e_2+e_3|+(|e_4|+\ldots+|e_n|)<1+(n-3)=n-2.
$$
Understandably similar reasoning in 3D.

All is well and wonderful.

> But why do the above three vertices exist? And in the case of 3D, four
> vertices?

How to justify this? That's actually my question.

> However, perhaps there is another solution to these problems using
> other considerations?

I will gladly accept such answers too.

**Adding.** (2024/01/11)
It seems to me that whether a polyhedron ($n$-gon) is convex or not does not matter.
I have posted a picture that clarifies this point.
We know that the vertices of the $n$-gon are located on the rays with origin at $O$.
There are many such $n$-gons, but the sum of the vectors depends only on the direction of the rays.
[image]

Comment: Is your polyhedron convex ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, No, it doesn't have to be convex. At least the condition doesn't say anything about that. I thought it was necessary to require convexity too, but I couldn't construct a counterexample.

Comment: For the $2D$ case, let's assume there is a vertex, say $A$, whose reflection, say $A'$ with respect to $O$ is not a vertex of the $n-$gon. Note that if there is no such a vertex, the inequality is vacuously correct. Now the line $AA'$ divides the circle into two parts, $P_1$ and $P_2$. Each part must contain some points. In $P_1$ pick the point that is at the greatest distance from $A$, say $A_1$, and similarly pick the point in $P_2$ that is at the greatest distance from $A$, say $A_2$. I think $A,A_1, A_2$ should work. OF course, this argument (if working)  depends on convexity.

Comment: Regarding the comment above, no points should lie between $A_1$ and $A_2$. Moreover, I can't think of a non-convex situation. A figure may clarify possible situations.

Comment: @RezaRajaei, thank you for your comments, I made an addition to my question.

Comment: You're welcome. I think now for the plane case everything is fine and your reasoning works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $O$ is in the interior of a polyhedron, then $O$ is also in the interior of the convex hull of the polyhedron.

Thus we don't need to assume that the polyhedron is convex.

In fact, we don't even need a polyhedron.

We'll use the following specifications . . .

With $n\ge 3$, let $v_1,...,v_n\in\mathbb{R}^m$, not necessarily distinct, but not all collinear.

It follows that $m\ge 2$.

Let $H$ be the convex hull of $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ and let $O$ be an interior point of $H$ with $O$ distinct from $v_1,...,v_n$.

Note that $H$ need not be $m$-dimensional, so an open subset of $H$ need not be open in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

For each $i\in\{1,...,n\}$ let $e_i$ be the unit vector directed from $O$ to $v_i$.

**Claim:**$\;|e_1+\cdots+e_n| < n-2$.

**Proof:**

Assume $v_1,...,v_k$ are the distinct extreme points of $H$.

Since $v_1,...,v_n$ are not all collinear, it follows that $k\ge 3$, so $3\le k\le n$.

Choose points $A,B,C$ in the interior of $H$ such that $A,B,C$ are the vertices of a non-degenerate triangle whose centroid is $O$.

Since $A,B,C$ are in the interior of $H$, we can write
\begin{align*}
A&=\sum_{i=1}^k a_iv_i\\[4pt]
B&=\sum_{i=1}^k b_iv_i\\[4pt]
C&=\sum_{i=1}^k c_iv_i\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
expressing each of $A,B,C$ as a convex combination of $v_1,...,v_k$.

Since $O$ is the centroid of triangle $ABC$, we get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k r_iv_i=0
$$
where $r_i=a_i+b_i+c_i$, hence
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k s_ie_i=0
$$
where $s_i=r_i|v_i|$.

Then letting
$$
S=\sum_{i=1}^k s_i
$$
we have the convex combination
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k t_ie_i=0
$$
where $t_i=s_i/S$.

Without loss of generality, assume $t_1\ge\cdots\ge t_k$.

Suppose $t_3=0$.

Then for all $i\in\{3,..,k\}$, we have $t_i=0$.

But from the implications
$$
t_i=0\implies s_i=0\implies r_i=0\implies a_i,b_i,c_i=0
$$
it would follow that $A,B,C$ are linear combinations of $v_1,v_2$.

But then $A,B,C$ would be collinear, contradiction, since triangle $ABC$ is non-degenerate.

Hence $t_3 > 0$, so $t_1,t_2,t_3 > 0$.

Since $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are distinct extreme points of $H$, they are not collinear, hence the vectors
$$
-t_1e_1,\;t_2e_2,\;t_3e_3
$$
are not all parallel.

Then we get
\begin{align*}
2t_1
&=
|-2t_1e_1|
\\[4pt]
&=
\left|
-2t_1e_1
+
\sum_{i=1}^k t_ie_i
\right|
\\[4pt]
&=
\left|
-t_1e_1
+
\sum_{i=2}^k t_ie_i
\right|
\\[4pt]
& < 
\sum_{i=1}^k |t_ie_i|
\qquad
\bigl(\text{strict inequality}\bigr)
\\[4pt]
&=
\sum_{i=1}^k t_i
\\[4pt]
&=
1
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence $2t_i < 1$ for all $i\in\{1,...,k\}$.

Then we get
\begin{align*}
\left|
\sum_{i=1}^k e_i
\right|
&=
\left|
\sum_{i=1}^k e_i
-
2\sum_{i=1}^k t_ie_i
\right|
\\[4pt]
&=
\left|
\sum_{i=1}^k (1-2t_i)e_i
\right|
\\[4pt]
& < 
\sum_{i=1}^k |(1-2t_i)e_i|
\qquad
\bigl(\text{strict inequality}\bigr)
\\[4pt]
&=
\sum_{i=1}^k (1-2t_i)
\\[4pt]
&=
k-2
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so then
\begin{align*}
\left|
\sum_{i=1}^n e_i
\right|
&=
\left|
\sum_{i=1}^k e_i
+
\sum_{i=k+1}^n e_i
\right|
\\[4pt]
&\le
\left|
\sum_{i=1}^k e_i
\right|
+
\left|
\sum_{i=k+1}^n e_i
\right|
\\[4pt]
& < 
(k-2)+(n-k)
\\[4pt]
&=
n-2
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
as was to be shown.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is an amazingly interesting solution. We see that the only thing that matters is that $O$ is an interior point of the convex hull of vertices.

Comment: I accept your answer. Unexpected and beautiful solution, I see three main points of this solution: 1) $O$ is an interior point, so there is a neighborhood of it lying inside; 
2) the sum of vectors directed from the centroid to the vertices of the triangle is $0$; 
3) the transition to the convex hull.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to try to outline a solution that uses an idea for the solution of the tetrahedron problem.

There is a polyhedron $\mathcal{P}$ with $n$ vertices and a point $O$ inside it.
Let $e_i=\vec{OA_i}$ be a unit vector directed from the point $O$ to the $i$-th vertex $A_i$ of the polyhedron.
We need to prove that
$$
|e_1+\ldots+e_n|<n-2.
$$

By contradiction.
Let $\vec{ON}=e_1+\ldots+e_n$ and $|\vec{ON}|\geq n-2$.

Let $P$ be a plane passing through $O$ and perpendicular to $\vec{ON}$.
If the vertices of $\mathcal{P}$ all lie above the plane $P$,
then the point $O$ is not an interior point of $\mathcal{P}$.
Therefore, there is at least one point  $A_i$ that lies below $P$.
The lowest point among those below $P$ is denoted by $A$ (see the figure).
[image]

Let $P_A$ be a plane passing through the point $A$ parallel to $P$ and
$P'_A$ be a plane centrally symmetric to $P_A$ with respect to the center $O$.
Let us call the line of intersection of the sphere and the plane $P_A$ (resp. $P'_A$)
South (resp. North) circle.

Consider an axis $L$ passing through $O$ and parallel to $\vec{ON}$.
We can look at $L$ as a number line, $1$ corresponds to the point of intersection of the ray $ON$ and the sphere.
Let $\pi$ be the orthogonal projection of $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto the $L$.
If $\pi(A_i)=a_i,\pi(N)=t$, then $|a_i|\leq1$, $t=|\vec{ON}|$ and $t=a_1+\ldots+a_n$.
Let $\pi(A)=a$. If $A=A_i$, then $a=a_i$ and we have $a<0$.

If there is a point $B\in\{A_1,\ldots,A_n\}$ south of North circle besides the point $A$
and $\pi(B)=b$, then $|b|<|a|$. Now, if $C\in\{A_1,\ldots,A_n\}\setminus\{A,B\}$ and $\pi(C)=c$, then $a+b+c<1$ and
$$
t=\sum_{A_i\not\in\{A,B,C\}}a_i+(a+b+c)\leq (a+b+c)+(n-3)<n-2.
$$
The latter contradicts our assumption.

Consequently, all points $A_i$ other than $A$ lie on or north of North circle.
In this case, all vertices of the polyhedron $\mathcal{P}$ lie on or above the plane $P_{OA}$ passing through $O$ and $A$
and perpendicular to the plane $P$.
So $O$ does not lie inside $P$.
The contradiction proves our statement.

**Adding.**
If a vertex $V$ of $\mathcal{P}$ lies below the plane $P_{OA}$, then the point of intersection of the ray $OV$ and the sphere is one of our points $A_k$ which lies south of North circle.

Comment: A very generalized solution [+1], but I was curious to know if you could show your initial guess as suggested in the body of the question.

Comment: @RezaRajaei, thank yuo very match. The initial guess has not been realized yet, but I keep thinking about it.

Comment: Very nice approach! [+1]. I followed your argument up to and including your claim that "all points $A_i$ other than $A$ lie on or north of North circle", but your next claim that "all vertices of the polyhedron $\mathcal{P}$ lie on or above the plane passing through $O$ and $A$ and perpendicular to the plane $P$" is not clear to me. Why can't there be vertices on both sides of that plane but still north of North circle?

Comment: As @quasi mentioned, we may work with the convex hull. Let's assume your initial guess is correct for polyhedrons having $5,6,...,n$ vertices; in other words, there are four vertices that form a tetrahedron containing the center. Let's prove the case for a polyhedron having $n+1$ vertices. As I mentioned earlier there must be a vertex whose refection with respect to the center is not a vertex, say $A$. WLOG, we assume $A=(0,0,-1)$. Now, consider the ray passing through $A$ and $O$. Two, cases happen. First, this ray passes through inside of a face of the polyhedron.

Comment: @quasi, Thank you very much for your comment and especially for your question. 
The thing is that already after I posted my answer, I too suddenly hesitated at this very point. 
In order not to make the comment too long, I included additional arguments in my answer.

Comment: Second, this ray intersects an edge of the polyhedron. The second case is easy; consider the points $A$, the ends of the intersected edge and another arbitrary vertex. With these four selected points, you still can establish your inequalities mentioned in the main body of your question. As for the first case, note that the face (through which the ray passes) and point $A$ form a polyhedron that contains $O$ (just consider the projection of the face onto the $xy$ plane). Now, if the face has less than $n$ vertices, by the induction assumption, we are done.

Comment: If the face has exactly $n$ vertices, we have a cone-like shape whose base is an $n$-gon. In this case, we can simply make use of the $2D-$case to conclude your guess. It's actually simple.

Comment: @RezaRajaei, It seems to me that you have another solution to this problem. Please post your solution here. By the way, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4843409/528593) is a very good review of your solution to the previous problem.

Comment: @kabenyuk Indeed, a detailed solution of the general idea I commented needs some work such as proving the plane case whose justification I posted as another comment. Moreover, your own solution is kind of an ultimate approach. However, I just was curious to verify your initial guess. Please, feel free to add (or polish up based on your interpretation of course) my comments inside the body of the OP if you think it can give future readers a sense of another possible approach.